# How to set icon to my jar using Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, jar

Hi I am using Visual Studio,
             I want to set icon to my jar file. But I donot know how to set icon file to my Jar file. So How can I set icon to my Jar file.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: What's the question again? :)

Comment: Hi I have created a jar file using netbeans. Now I am creating installer for my jar file. That is possible using visual studio. So I want to set icon image to that jar file. Because the default jar image is default image of sun. I want to change that. SO how to set my own image to that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are creating a Setup project in VS and have a .jar file as an installable item. I might be wrong but I don't think you can change the icon of this file as the OS has a standard icon associated with all file types. If you're yourself creating a .net .exe then you get the option to specify an icon for this assembly through Project Properties -> Application -> Icon and manifest setting.

If you want to change the icon associated with .jar files (all .jar files on your system and not just one .jar file), then try this:
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/change-file-icon/

The above change will change the default icon associated to a file type (.jar in our case) and will show the icon of your choice. But I think this setting will work only on your system. On the target system where you aim to deploy this .jar file, it'll show the icon that is configured for .jar files on that system.

Let me know if I got the question wrong.